# Remote website images reduce page speed wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, performance, optimization, lazy-loading

I have website and i have lots of images on home page.

Almost 60 images in row and i have almost 5 rows of carousel.

But all this image comes from remote website feed so i cant optimize them and the occupy lots of size

when i test my website in gt matrix it shows me 26mb of page so it is obvious it will take
much loading time.I have applied lazy loading images,how ever the speed is very slow

What steps should i take to speed up this kind of page?I dont want to use any plugin because they brake website some times

Answer (score 0):

Upon showing images from another server makes the site slow, because that server may be slow.
So better you try to get those images from your server if possible, else you can try using

1. plugins like wp-supercache
2. Minify all your JS and CSS files

Answer (score 0):

For better page speed and avoid these error you should try following things.

1. Enable Compression from Cpanel
2. You are using Wordpress so use any of the cache plugin.
3. Use header expiry using httaccess or page header.
4. minimize you scripts (css,js).
5. Use compressed images (jpegtran,pngout).
6. If your image is casing issue try to use CDN for images.

This will help you to improve page speed.

Comment: the images are already served from different site and not my site so is it cdn possible with this?

Comment: Images from other server , so CDN will not help you, If you are storing those images there then you should compress images(like cloud storage). Otherwise the images will be large in size.

Answer (score 0):

Crop the images using [timthumb](http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/). There is wordpress plugins for timthumb probably. Check in wordpress directory as well as it's use. Once images size is reduced, Page would be loaded fast. Additionally, follow the @Jobin Jose's comment, will help you to optimize the speed. Moreover, use [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) plugins.